# Como nomear automaticamente uma CONSTRAINT criada manualmente no SQLServer 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Olá, estou criando uma base de dados e preciso criar alguns indexes compostos para otimizar o processamento do banco. O problema é que não quero ter que nomear esses indexes um-a-um. Normalmente, eu crio uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    email NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    senha NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '123',
)
```

Ao criar essa tabela, automaticamente o SQLServer já gera para mim as CONSTRAINT para os campos email (UNIQUE) e senha (DEFAULT). O problema é quando eu tenho que criar um index composto, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Bar (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Bin (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FooId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Foo(id),
    BarId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bar(id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UX_Bin_FooIdBarId] ON Bin(FooId, BarId);
```

Existe alguma forma ou declaração ou caractere coringa que eu possa utilizar na declaração desse index para que ele seja nomeado automaticamente? ou então alguma outra forma de criar esse index composto para que tenha o mesmo resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o Ricardo Pontual comentou, é obrigatório informar o nome de constraints criadas fora do comando `CREATE TABLE`.

Porém, é possível criar constraints mais complexas já na criação da tabela, não precisando assim nomeá-las manualmente. Considerando o seu exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Bin (
  id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  FooId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Foo(id),
  BarId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Bar(id),
  UNIQUE(FooId, BarId)
);
```

Lembrando que você pode também usar essa declaração para definir outras constraints ou índices sobre a tabela, como por exemplo, uma `CHECK` constraint que verifica duas colunas da tabela ou até mesmo uma chave estrangeira composta.

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado mesmo! É um saco ter que ficar nomeando essas referências... rs

Answer (score 1):

Não se você quiser usar o comando `create index`, o nome é obrigatório: [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

O que acontece como você já sabe é que quando você usa `create table` ou `alter table` e criar *constraints* ou índices (chave primária por exemplo) implicitamente (usando default, unique, etc), o `sql-server` se encarrega de nomear, mas se criar explicitamente usando o comando create precisa dar um nome.